# Moving archive title, breadcrumb and pagination into a div - Woocommerce - Wordress - Genesis

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, woocommerce, genesis

I'm using the Genesis Framework for Wordpress with Woocommerce. I'm trying to move the Archive title & description along with the breadcrumb and pagination outside of the main container.

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
<div class="new-header"><div class="wrap">
**Breadcrumb** 
**Title & Description**
**Pagination**
</div></div>
```

This is my attempt which adds in the new divs but doesn't include any of the other elements.

```
function my_new_cat_header() {

    echo '<div class="woo-cat-header"><div class="wrap">';

    // Add breadcrumbs to woocommerce
    add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 99 );

    //Move category (archive) title and description outside of the container
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
    add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );

    // Show woocommerce pagination on the top of shop page
    add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );

    echo '</div></div>';
}

add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'my_new_cat_header' );
```

Any help, feedback or support would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could achieve this. I'm sure there may be better ways to do this.

```
//* Remove stuffs
remove_action( 'woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );

//* Start of the div
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'my_new_cat_header_start' );
function my_new_cat_header_start() {
    echo '<div class="woo-cat-header"><div class="wrap">';
}

// Add breadcrumbs to woocommerce
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb' );
function woocommerce_breadcrumb() {
    echo "bread";
}

//Move category (archive) title and description outside of the container
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description' );
function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() {
    echo "description";
}

// Show woocommerce pagination on the top of shop page
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_pagination' );
function woocommerce_pagination() {
    echo "pagination";
}

//* Ending of the div
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'my_new_cat_header_end' );
function my_new_cat_header_end() {  
    echo '</div></div>';
}
```

This is how above code outputted in my local server.

```
<div class="woo-cat-header">
<div class="wrap">breaddescriptionpagination</div>
</div>
```

If you've added more stuffs to `genesis_after_header` hook, you may need to use proper priority number such as `add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 15 );`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for that.

What you've given me works but obviously doesn't include the functions to add the Title, Pagination and Breadcrumbs which is what I'm having trouble with.

As soon as I add those functions they don't get moved and I am therefore left with an empty div. I even tried the priorities like you mentioned and that sadly didn't work either.

Have you any further ideas please?